# Error code 42601 in postgreSQL pg-promise, in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, asynchronous, pg-promise

I'm trying to make a bulk Insert/Update data in a db, but I have got this error, I don't know why, this is my code

This is the function of the promise of the bulkInsert

```
async bulkInsertFeatureTreatment(req, res) {
const { featuresTreatments } = await decryptRequest(req);
await db
  .tx((t) => {
    const queries = featuresTreatments.map((featureTreatment) => {
      return t.none(
        featuresTreatmentsDB.insertFeatureTreatment(featureTreatment)
      );
    });
    return t.batch(queries);
  })
  .then((data) =>
    cryptedResponse(res, response(200, INSERT_DATA_SUCCESS, data))
  )
  .catch((error) =>
    cryptedResponse(res, response(500, INSERT_DATA_NOT_SUCCESS, error))
  );
```

}

this is the function of insert/update, the upper function calls this

```
insertFeatureTreatment: (featuresTreatments) =>
`INSERT INTO ${TABLE_NAME} (${COL_ID_TREATMENT}, ${COL_ID_FEATURE}, ${COL_VALUE})
VALUES ('${featuresTreatments.id_treatment}', '${featuresTreatments.id_feature}', '${featuresTreatments.value}')
ON CONFLICT (${COL_ID_TREATMENT}, ${COL_ID_FEATURE}) 
DO UPDATE ${TABLE_NAME} 
SET ${COL_VALUE} = '${featuresTreatments.value}'
WHERE ${COL_ID_TREATMENT} = '${featuresTreatments.id_treatment}' 
AND ${COL_ID_FEATURE} = '${featuresTreatments.id_feature}'`,
```

Comment: Maybe one query fails, did you try to perform the queries directly in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Your code shows that you are concatenating everything for SQL manually, That's a strict no-no for database programming. There is no telling what final SQL may look like, it can end up being completely broken.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was a syntax error, it were about the conflict syntax, so this is the result:

```
insertFeatureTreatment: (featuresTreatments) =>
```

`INSERT INTO ${TABLE_NAME} (${COL_ID_TREATMENT}, ${COL_ID_FEATURE}, ${COL_VALUE}) VALUES ('${featuresTreatments.id_treatment}', '${featuresTreatments.id_feature}', '${featuresTreatments.value}') ON CONFLICT (${COL_ID_TREATMENT}, ${COL_ID_FEATURE})  DO UPDATE SET ${COL_VALUE} = '${featuresTreatments.value}'`,